# How to get base table of a column in a view in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a view with some columns in it.
How to check that those columns of the views is extracted from which base table?
How to get base table of a column in a view in oracle?

Comment: As long as you've tagged SQL Developer, you may CTRL+Click on the view name to open its definition and check the text.

Comment: The issue is that column may be an *expression* and can be calculated on top of many columns. A brief solution is to use the result of `explain plan` statement applied to the select of this column. Then display its result with `+PROJECTION` format option. Oracle doesn't use columns that do not participate in a result, but it requests, for example, join columns. And you have to track them down and separate them from the columns used in calculation. See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=03fecd81ae2adba6b528754b3e90d905)

Comment: Also please note that XMLTable, JSON_TABLE and pipelined functions are valid rowsources and it's quite hard to track down column usage (without repetition of SQL parsing algorithm)

Comment: Aside from your IDE to be SQL Developer, you can always get them by querying the `user_views` such as `SELECT text FROM user_views`.